# How can i change my image as the listener?

Tags: javascript

I have some trouble with my javascript

I have two images. When I wanna click randomly an image, it will be replaced with the image in the JS. if I click on the rest image, it also will be replaced like the previous image but the previous image will return to the original image. How can I do that??

Thanks a lot.

This is my code. Sorry for my bad English skills

```js
function openPresent(event){
  
    event.target.src ='https://i2.wp.com/gsviec.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/coder-dev-1.jpeg?fit=900%2C500&ssl=1';
    
}

  const image = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  let i;
  for(i=0;i<image.length;i++){
    image[i].addEventListener('click',openPresent);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
     <script src='script.js'defer></script>
</head>
<body>
      <h1>Click for a present:</h1>
      <img src=https://timviec365.com/pictures/images/coder-la-gi-3.jpg>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <img src="https://img.timviec.com.vn/2020/10/coder-la-gi-2.jpg">
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your original image `src` in an array. When changing the `src` on click, revert all the `src`s to original and just change the one for target.

Have a look at this:

```js
function openPresent(event){
  
  const image = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  for(let i=0;i<image.length;i++){
    image[i].src= originalImagesSrcArray[i];
  }
  
  event.target.src ='https://i2.wp.com/gsviec.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/coder-dev-1.jpeg?fit=900%2C500&ssl=1';
    
}

  const image = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  let i;

let originalImagesSrcArray = [];
for(i=0;i<image.length;i++){
  originalImagesSrcArray.push(image[i].getAttribute('src'));  image[i].addEventListener('click',openPresent);
  }
  
  console.log(originalImagesSrcArray);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
     <script src='script.js'defer></script>
</head>
<body>
      <h1>Click for a present:</h1>
      <img src="https://timviec365.com/pictures/images/coder-la-gi-3.jpg">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <img src="https://img.timviec.com.vn/2020/10/coder-la-gi-2.jpg">
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Sure. Please accept the answer using green tick if it helped you. Consider upvoting

Comment: sorry, my bad. I am newbie